# function to reverse a linked list using recursion in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I have to write a function to reverse a linked list using recursion in C++. I did it and the reasoning seems correct to me, but the code is not working. Could someone explain me why? Thank you all!

This is the function:

```
list* reverseList(list* head, list* p, list* n){

    if(head->next == NULL){
        head->next = p;
        p = head;
        head = n;
        n = NULL;
        return head;
    }

    else{
        head->next = p;
        p = head;
        head = n;
        n = n->next;
        return reverseList(head, p, n);
    }

}
```

This is the list struct:

```
struct list{
    int val;
    list *next;
};
```

This is the main:

```
int main() {
    list *head, *p1, *p2, *prev, *next;

    head = new list;
    head->val = 1;
    p1 = new_node(head, 2);
    p2 = new_node(p1, 3);
    p2->next = NULL;
    print_list(head);

    prev = NULL;
    next = head->next;

    reverseList(head, prev, next);
    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

And these are other functions i use to create new nodes with values and to print the list:

```
list* new_node(list* old_node, int value)
{
    old_node->next = new list;
    old_node->next->val = value;
    return old_node->next;
}

void print_list(list* head){
    while(head != NULL){
        cout << head->val << endl;
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add that `main` and post a snip-it that can be copied, compiled and run. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add complete code so we can compile and see the result. Hint: `*p` is a pointer but `p` is just a local to function won't make any changes at calling function

Comment: I added all the code needed to compile

Comment: Just traverse untill linked list is null, and when function retrun your last value is in stack and you can print or store the value in some array or something if(p->next == null) cout << p->data else p=p->next; p is pointer to a list

Comment: It seems to work, what you need to do is `print_list(p2);` The head is no longer the head after you reverse it.

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code,

1. Return value of `reverseList` is not collected and it should be `head = reverseList(head, prev, next);`
2. Inside `reverseList` on `head->next == NULL` you need to return previous pointer rather next pointer which is anyhow pointing to NULL.

```
list* reverseList(list* head, list* p, list* n) {
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        head->next = p;
        return head;
    }
    else {
        head->next = p;
        p = head;
        head = n;
        n = n->next;
        return reverseList(head, p, n);
    }
}
```

which can even be simplified to,

```
void reverseList(list* &head, list* &p) {
    if (!head) return;
    list* t = head->next;
    head->next = p;
    p = head;
    if (t)
    {
        head = t;
        reverseList(head, p);
    }
}
```

and called like `reverseList(head, prev);`